# Get columns from two dataframes where values differ

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two almost identical Pyspark dataframes: same number of rows and row_id, same schema, but different values on some of columns for each row.

I want to identify what are those columns for each row.

Example:

Dataframe A

```
id  fname   lname   email
1   Michael Jackson mj@yahoo.com
2   Roger   Moore   rm@rocketmail.com
3   Angela  Merkel  am@dw.de
```

Dataframe B

```
id  fname   lname   email
1   Michael Jordan  mj@yahoo.com
2   Gordon  Moore   rm@rocketmail.com
3   Angela  Markle  am@dw.com
```

The expected output is a list of dictionaries:

```
[ 
  {"1": ["lname"]}, 
  {"2": ["fname"] }, 
  {"3": ["lname", "email"] }
]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a more generalized answer, using RDD conversion:

```
column_names = a_df.schema.names

def compare(row):
    diff_columns = []
    for col in column_names:
        if row[1][0][col] != row[1][1][col]:
            diff_columns.append(col)

    return ( row[0],  { row[0]: diff_columns } )

# convert to Pair RDD for joining
a_pair_rdd = a_df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x['id'], x))
b_pair_rdd = b_df.rdd.map(lambda y: (y['id'], y))
joined_rdd = a_pair_rdd.join(b_pair_rdd)

output = joined_rdd.map(compare).map(lambda pair: pair[1]).collect()
```